# How to embed Facebook application on fanpage?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have created the application, but does not appear on the side of the button "App Profile Page View" in the settings page of the application.

Already added the addresses to the iFrame fan page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I got you right, so here is my answer:
Facebook [announced](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/) that they will not not create App Profile pages on App creation anymore. This was usually the place  Developers went to add an App's Tab to a Fan page.

You now have a few options:

1. Replace `YOUR_APP_ID` and `YOUR_URL` in https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL with the values of the App you want to add as a Tab to your Fan Page
2. If you want to give others an easy way to add your App's Tab to their Fan Pages, use the "Add Page Tab" Dialog, you can read about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/)
3. Use a third party Tool that allows you to add App Tabs to your Fan Pages (I wrote one but won't link it here as I won't self advertise my tools). But if you want to have the URL to it, I will give it to you upon request.

Cheers,
Björn

Comment: Hello, can you give this url? Thanks.